# Is there a way to use a phone as a virtual keychain for NFC tags?

Tags: applications, security, nfc

So let's say I have a bunch of things that can be unlocked via NFC. Each thing would correspond with *one* tag and *one* tag only. The problem would then be that I'd have to carry a bunch of tags around. What would make this much more easy to manage, would be to use a phone as a keychain for these tags. A keychain in the sense that all tags would be virtually stored on the phone. When I then would need to use a tag to unlock its corresponding thing, I'd need to emulate the tag through the phone.

The question is then: is there a method available to store multiple virtual NFC tags on the phone, and can the phone in turn act as a tag emulator?

P.S. My current phone doesn't support NFC, but my near-future phone will (and it will of course have the latest Android version that's available at that time).